# BindToMoniker opens a new excel session

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

The following code tries to attach to an excel session that has the C:\test file opened. If such a session doesn't exist, this either returns null or throws an exception.

```
 var myExcelWorkbook = Marshal.BindToMoniker(@"C:\test") as Excel.Workbook;
```

This works very well when the file has no extension. However if I am trying the exact same code with a file that has an extension (for instance C:\test.xlsb), the call tries to open that file with excel before returning. If an instance is already running, it will try to open the file in that instance (as if someone double-clicked on that file in the windows explorer).

```
 var myExcelWorkbook = Marshal.BindToMoniker(@"C:\test.xlsb") as Excel.Workbook;
```

This definitely has to do with the extension (how would BindToMoniker know how to open Excel otherwise?), but is very annoying, since I never want to attach to an existing excel session that doesn't have that file already opened.

Is there a way to disable that "feature"? I would like that the BindToMoniker method never tries to open a file and let me decide what to do in the various cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely with how Excel documents are named in "running objects table" rather than presence of extension.

Read on IRunningObjectTable... There is [IRunningObjectTable.EnumRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.irunningobjecttable.enumrunning) which may be useful.

Comment: Ok but, if there is no excel open at all, the running object table is empty of excel objects. Why would `BindToMoniker("C:\test.xlsb")` open excel and `BindToMoniker("C:\test")` not?

Comment: Nevermind, what I did is loop through the object in the running table and if I don't find the one I am looking for, I don't call BindToMoniker. Thanks for the advice

Comment: You are lucky that checking ROT first worked for your case. To learn inner working - start reading real docs [IMoniker::BindToObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889312.aspx) (link is to Win CE, can't find better one).

Comment: Yes, I will check that. I was hoping this would be a 30-minutes task, but it is turning into pretty deep windows programming (way more than I would have liked)